# How set Array/List in Spring jdbcTemplate as parameter?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc

I have SQL query with many placeholders '?', that builds dynamically, I want to put array of values to replace placeholders. Size of array can be different every time. Array consists from all parameters in order.

```
return jdbcTemplate.query(Queries.someQuery,
    new Object[] {/* Array must be here */},
    new ResultSetExtractor<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public List<String> extractData(ResultSet resultSet) 
        }
    });
```

Example of sql generations:

```
for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        conditionsBuilder.append("\n and p"+i+".object_id=o.object_id\n" +
                "    and p"+i+".attr_id =?\n" +
                "    and p"+i+".value =?\n");
        tablesBuilder.append(",patameters p"+i+" ");
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Object> values = new ArrayList<>;
```

In your `for` loop you should add the values in the order they appear in the query:

```
values.add(value);
```

Then turn it into an array:

```
return jdbcTemplate.query(query, values.toArray(), resultSetExtractor);
```